# How to use existing ASP.NET authentication tables from IdentityServer4 in OpenIddict

Tags: identityserver4, openiddict

We currently have existing ASP.NET Userclaims in IS4, and we would like to use them in OpenIddict for our project. We want our OpenIddict implementation to use the same tables because we already have existing claims, with their related entities in these ASP.Net tables. During the setup of we did an initial migration, during which we added a prefix to the ASP.NET Identity tables
`OI_AspNetUserClaims`
for example. Is this even possible? And if so, how can we achieve it?

Could anyone help us with making this step?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

OpenIddict doesn't handle the user authentication part at all, which is something you must implement yourself: assuming you're still using ASP.NET Core Identity to handle user authentication, you can of course keep using the existing Identity tables.

Comment: Migrating from IDSVR4 to OpenIddict; have same/similar question. Plan to try using `services.AddOpenIddict().AddCore(options => { options.UseEntityFrameworkCore().UseDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>();});`  Found in [Register your Entity Framework Core database context and configure the OpenIddict core services](https://documentation.openiddict.com/guides/getting-started/creating-your-own-server-instance.html#:~:text=Register%20your%20Entity%20Framework%20Core%20database%20context%20and%20configure%20the%20OpenIddict%20core%20services)

Comment: @ttugates you can use the EF Core stores for the OpenIddict entities, but it's unrelated to the Identity configuration, which is completely independent from OpenIddict. Take a look at the samples in https://github.com/openiddict/openiddict-samples to see you can create your own `AuthorizationController` that will serve as a link between OpenIddict and Identity.